# Unable to parse complex nested JSON flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing, null

I'm getting null data (venue details, branch details and their nested data) when fetching in the flutter app, but it shows non-null data on postman, it means api is giving correct response, but the function is unable to get it, this is my function, `

```
Future<bool> getPresentOrders({
    required token,
    required userId,
  }) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(BASE_URL + '/api/get_present_orders'),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
        },
        body: jsonEncode({
          'user_id': userId,
        }),
      );

      // final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);

      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body)['success']
          as List<dynamic>?; // Map<String, dynamic>;

      print('getting pending orders $extractedData');

      if (extractedData == null) {
        return false;
      }

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<Order> loadedOrderList = [];

        extractedData.forEach((prodData) {
          if (
          prodData != null &&
          prodData['venue_detail'] != null &&
              prodData['branch_detail'] != null) {
            loadedOrderList.add(
              Order(
                venueId: prodData['venue_id'].toString(),
                branchId: prodData['branch_id'].toString(),
                orderNumber: prodData['order_unique_id'],
                orderTime: prodData['order_time'],
                total: prodData['total_price'],
                orderType: prodData['order_type'],
                currentStatus: prodData['current_status'],
                venueName: prodData['venue_detail']['venue_name'],
                venueType: prodData['venue_detail']['venue_type'],
                branchName: prodData['branch_detail'] != null
                    ? prodData['branch_detail']['name']
                    : 'Branch',
                venueLogo:
                prodData['venue_detail']['logo_url'],
                orderItems: (json.decode(prodData['items_detail'])
                        // .substring(1, prodData['items_detail'].length - 1)
                        // .split(' ","')
                        as List<dynamic>)
                    .map((item) =>
                        // CartItem(id: '1', title: '2', quantity: 3, price: 4))
                        CartItem(
                          id: item['id'].toString(),
                          title: item['title'].toString(),
                          quantity: int.parse(item['quantity'].toString()),
                          price: double.parse(item['price'].toString()),
                          specialInstruction: item['instructions'].toString(),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
                // venueName:
              ),
            );
          }
        });

        // print('now printing my model data');
        loadedOrderList.forEach((element) {});
        _or = loadedOrderList.reversed.toList();
      } else {
        print('Something Went Wrong!');
      }

      notifyListeners();
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }`
```

Can someone help me solving this? the problem is actually occuring in venue details and branch details params, this is the response, please check and suggest a solution.

```
 {
    "success": [ {
            "id": 35,
            "user_id": 1,
            "order_unique_id": "7487",
            "venue_id": 1,
            "branch_id": 1,
            "category_id": 1,
            "sub_category_id": 1,
            "items_detail": "[{\"id\":\"1\",\"title\":\"كراهي\",\"quantity\":1,\"price\":50.0,\"instructions\":\"\",\"image\":\"https://adminportal.urmenuz.com/public/uploads/menu_images/1689758678.jpg\"}]",
            "total_price": "50.00",
            "wallet_amount": "0.00",
            "payment_method_amount": "50.00",
            "service_fee": "0.00",
            "additional_fee": null,
            "payment_method": "cod",
            "add_ons": "[]",
            "table_number": null,
            "order_type": "dine_in",
            "curbside_pickup_details": null,
            "additional_remarks": "xyz",
            "reviews": "abc",
            "order_time": "2023-08-19 13:10:07",
            "in_kichen_time": null,
            "order_ready_time": null,
            "order_completion_time": null,
            "current_status": "pending",
            "is_rated": 0,
            "is_paid": 0,
            "cc_number": null,
            "created_at": "2023-08-19T08:10:07.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-08-19T08:10:07.000000Z",
            "venue_detail": {
                "id": 1,
                "customer_id": 1,
                "venue_name": "Chilli Chutney",
                "description": null,
                "facebook_url": "https://www.facebook.com/",
                "insta_url": "https://www.instagram.com",
                "cuisine_type": null,
                "venue_type": "FSR",
                "venue_logo": "1690186873.png",
                "banner": null,
                "is_available": 1,
                "status": "Active",
                "view_type": "list_view",
                "created_at": "2023-07-19T09:06:50.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-07-24T08:21:13.000000Z",
                "logo_url": "https://adminportal.urmenuz.com/uploads/logos/1690186873.png",
                "banner_url": "https://adminportal.urmenuz.com/uploads/banners/"
            },
            "branch_detail": {
                "id": 1,
                "venue_id": 1,
                "name": "Salt Chilli Spy",
                "country": "Saudi Arabia",
                "city": "Dammam",
                "latitude": "23.95555172",
                "longitude": "42.51512301",
                "closing_hour": null,
                "attributes": null,
                "facebook_url": "https://www.facebook.com/",
                "insta_url": "https://www.instagram.com",
                "dine_in_banner": "1689757787.jpg",
                "pick_up_banner": "1689757777.jpg",
                "branch_manager_name": "ali",
                "branch_manager_email": "ali@gmail.com",
                "services_type": null,
                "is_dine_in": 1,
                "is_pick_up": 1,
                "is_pick_up_curb": 0,
                "is_available": 1,
                "status": "Active",
                "created_at": "2023-07-19T09:09:38.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2023-07-25T08:01:05.000000Z",
                "banner_pickup_url": "https://adminportal.urmenuz.com/uploads/banners/1689757777.jpg",
                "banner_dine_url": "https://adminportal.urmenuz.com/uploads/banners/1689757787.jpg"
            },
            "web_items": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "كراهي",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "price": 50,
                    "instructions": "",
                    "image": "https://adminportal.urmenuz.com/public/uploads/menu_images/1689758678.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "web_addons": []
        }, ]}
```

Comment: If that's the full response there is no field called `"success"` that you are trying to access so it immediately returns false

Comment: Sorry, I'm posting the full response now, it has "success".

Comment: Make sure to add the appropriate language tag for the language you are posting code in, I added the Dart tag for you.

Comment: This is a thorny JSON to unpack into Dart objects.  Have you done the Dart 3 codelab on records and patterns?  That might help. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/dart-patterns-records

Comment: the problem is in venue_detail and branch_detail, all other data is fetched correctly

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the only issue but one thing is that it's wrong to decode twice

```
orderItems: (json.decode(prodData['items_detail']) as List<dynamic>)
```

should just be

```
orderItems: (prodData['items_detail'] as List<dynamic>)
```

The initial decode made it recursively into maps and lists and such

Comment: no, the problem is in venue_detail and branch_detail, all other data is fetched correctly